# Laravel ManyToMany relationship on same model

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent, relationship

I'm trying to make a bidirectional ManyToMany relationship on my Tag model, but I ran into this "issue".

My model looks like this:

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Tag extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'tags';
    public $timestamps = false;

    public function tags()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Tag::class, 'tag_tag', 'tag_one_id', 'tag_two_id');
    }

}
```

So at the moment let's say I have Tag1 and Tag2 in my tags table, and then I'll relate the Tag2 with the Tag1.
Now my pivot table will look like this:

```
+----+------------+------------+
| id | tag_one_id | tag_two_id |
+----+------------+------------+
| 1  | 1          | 2          |
+----+------------+------------+
```

When I try this code:

```
$tag = Tag::find(1);
$tag->tags()->get();
```

I get the Tag2 instance, and it is correct.

But when I try to run this code:

```
$tag = Tag::find(2);
$tag->tags()->get();
```

I would like to receive the Tag1 instance, but I don't.

Is it possible to get it done with Laravel default Eloquent using just one method on the model?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I found a solution and I solved it like this.

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Tag extends Model
{
    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $table = 'tags';

    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     *
     * @var bool
     */
    public $timestamps = false;

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | RELATIONS
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    */

    /**
     * Every tag can contain many related tags (TagOne has many TagTwo).
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\BelongsToMany
     */
    protected function tagsOneTwo()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Tag::class, 'tag_tag', 'tag_one_id', 'tag_two_id');
    }

    /**
     * Every tag can contain many related tags (TagTwo has many TagOne).
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\BelongsToMany
     */
    protected function tagsTwoOne()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Tag::class, 'tag_tag', 'tag_two_id', 'tag_one_id');
    }

    /**
     * This method returns a collection with all the tags related with this tag.
     * It is not a real relation, but emulates it.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection
     */
    public function tags()
    {
        return $this->tagsOneTwo()->get()->merge($this->tagsTwoOne()->get())->unique('id');
    }

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | FUNCTIONS
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    */

    /**
     * Function to relate two tags together.
     *
     * @param Tag $tag
     * @return void;
     */
    public function attach(Tag $tag)
    {
        if ($this->tags()->contains('id', $tag->getKey())) {
            return;
        }

        $this->tagsOneTwo()->attach($tag->getKey());
    }

    /**
     * Function to un-relate two tags.
     *
     * @param Tag $tag
     * @return void;
     */
    public function detach(Tag $tag)
    {
        if ($this->tags()->contains('id', $tag->getKey())) {
            // Detach the relationship in both ways.
            $this->tagsOneTwo()->detach($tag->getKey());
            $this->tagsTwoOne()->detach($tag->getKey());
        }
    }

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | ACCESORS
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    */

    /**
     * Let access the related tags like if it was preloaded ($tag->tags).
     *
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function getTagsAttribute()
    {
        if (! array_key_exists('tags', $this->relations)) {
            $this->setRelation('tags', $this->tags());
        };

        return $this->getRelation('tags');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

**Why it's not working?**

It's not working because in the relationship you added in `Tag` model is defined to work for one way. But not the reverse way.

It would work if we could have defined two method called `tags()` as below:

```
public function tags()
{
  return $this->belongsToMany(Tag::class, 'tag_tag', 'tag_one_id', 'tag_two_id');
}

//and

public function tags()
{
  return $this->belongsToMany(Tag::class, 'tag_tag', 'tag_two_id', 'tag_one_id');
}
```

Unfortunately, it's not possible.

**So, what can be possible solution**

One possible solution can be, don't touch the relationship. Instead if you somehow can manage to insert two relationship for these relationship then it will work. 
For example:

```
+----+------------+------------+
| id | tag_one_id | tag_two_id |
+----+------------+------------+
| 1  | 1          | 2          |
+----+------------+------------+
| 1  | 2          | 1          |
+----+------------+------------+
```

This is the solution coming out of my mind right now. There might be a better solution too.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible. You would have to pass a parameter to the `tags()` method and modify the primary/foreign key fields on the relationship using that parameter. That might be an total pain to have to deal with though and it would almost certainly be less of a headache to just make a second relationship method. It would just end up looking like this:

```
public function tags($tag1 = 'tag_one_id', $tag2 = 'tag_two_id')
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Tag::class, 'tag_tag', $tag1, $tag2);
}
```

and then you would just have to modify the values when you need `Tag::find(2)->tags('tag_two_id', 'tag_one_id')`

This *can* be eager loaded as described here: https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/general-discussion/eager-load-with-parameters

Your use case might be a lot more complicated than your post suggests, which might make this more reasonable. As it is I would consider a few of the other options.

Comment: Actually, I already thought about this, but the problem is that I have to merge both relationships (the tag_one_id -> tag_two_id and tag_two_id -> tag_one_id).

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean.

Comment: I was hoping for something like that, but in a way that I could return still a relationship from the method. https://stackoverflow.com/a/46316876/5280969

Comment: Ah, so you don't want the query builder to execute the SQL. So like the accessor in that example but it returns a relationship instead?

Comment: Yes, exactly, is it possible?

Comment: Not certain. The problem is you just end up with a collection of both tags at the same level, without any real way to notice they are related. It would be the same as just getting both tags `Tag::whereIn('id', $ids)->get()` would return the same thing if you passed the tag ids that you need. I'm trying to figure out the use case for this.

Comment: I'll tell you then what I'm trying to use it for.
I have the Tag entity that has a name, but I also need to store translations of that Tag.
Let's say I have the tag "Car", I also have "Automobile" or "Voiture" in different languages. But those are also different tags. So when I query for the tag "Car" I also have to retrieve the related tags ("Automobile" and "Voiture").
When I query "Voiture" I have to retrieve the relateds ("Car" and "Automobile").

Comment: What about eager loading the tags, and the tags of that tag. Like `Tag::with('tags', 'tags.tags')`. This should allow you to get all tags related to the current tag, and the tags related to those. So that way if you have a relationship between Car and Automobile, and Automobile and Voiture, you can still access Voiture from Car.

Comment: I tried but id didn't work, I think that I'll made a package that handles such relationships.